# Read-only DC lost connection and client can't sign in

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, read-only, trust-relationship

we have two site (office & factory). in factory site we have read-only Domain controller. connection of two sites is radio wireless and yesterday we lost connection because of storm. now users can't sign-in factory's clients. they see error about lost trust relationship. and repairing connection maybe last two days. if users unplug network cable in factory, they can sign-in and access files but shared drive in factory can't accessed. I change permission of drive share to "everyone" and turn off firewall of client both side(on has shared driver in factory and other clients want to use it) but no chance. what should i do in this position until connection repairs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could physically move server the read only DC is running on to other site, connect it to the the network there then demote it and re-promote it as a full DC and take it back to the other site. You should avoid running without a connection between the DC's for too long as it would eventually get tombstoned but as in the short term it would be OK.

Alternatively you could create another DC on a temporary server and take that to the the other site. If you don't have a spare server you could run a DC on pretty much any hardware as a temporary measure, even an old desktop or laptop.

Comment: I am not sure I got it right, in first solution you mean I put away RODC? and what happens after connection get repaired? I would have two distinct DC, how they would be synchronize?

Comment: Yes demote the RODC and then promote it as a full DC. You'd need to have connectivity to the other​ DC to do this and the initial promotion and replication which is why you'd have to physically move it to the other site. When you move it back replication won't work until the connection is back up but that will be OK for a few days. Too long without replication and you'd have a problem but for a short period it's Ok. You should avoid making conflicting changes while you've got no  replication.